# PHP ignore/skip empty fields in output from form

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm creating a HTML user form that when submitted, it gets posted to a PHP page to print on screen what the user typed in the form fields.

My problem:
With my existing PHP script, it writes a blank line where no data is in the HTML field. I want the results to skip the whole line if a HTML field was left blank by the user. Is this possible?

I have a pretty standard form. I use $_POST. 
I currently use this:

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST['fax'])) { 
echo "Fax&nbsp;"; echo $_POST['fax'];} ?><br>
```

But it leaves a blank line. The result should be a complete email signature. It looks something like this

```
Lisa Simpson
CEO
Board of Directors

Tel.: 213123
Fax: 123123
Mobile: 123123
```

I want that if the user doesn't have a faxnumber and leaves it blank, it should look like this:

```
Lisa Simpson
CEO
Board of Directors

Tel.: 213123
Mobile: 123123
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `<br>` tag id outside of the condition, So either value is there or not `<br>` will going to execute and give empty line. Try like this:-

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST['fax'])) { 
echo "Fax&nbsp;"; echo $_POST['fax'].'<br>';} ?>
```

Note:- You need to do it for all your `!empty` conditions.thanks. The above code gives new line only if values are there otherwise nothing will be output.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect. Sometimes you overview the simplest things :).

Comment: Yup.But i think it's common with all of us.No worry.:):):):):)

Answer (score 1):

Check if the length of the $_POST['fax'] variable is greater than 0, then you will know for sure if it has been set.

```
 if (strlen($_POST['fax']) > 0) { 
    echo "Fax: " . $_POST['fax'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I't seems that you sends the 
 eahn time, causing the blank line.

Yo can correct it using:

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST['fax'])) { 
  echo "Fax&nbsp;"; echo $_POST['fax']."<br>";
 } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

move your `<br>` tag in if statement

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This :-
<?php if (!empty($_POST['fax'])) { 
echo "<br> Fax&nbsp;"; echo $_POST['fax'];} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

elegant way

```
// binding data
$template = [
    'key' => ['text', null]
    'kye2' => ['text', null],
];

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    foreach ($template as $template_key => $template_value)
        if ($key == $template_key)
            $result[] = $template_value['1'] = $value;

//display data
foreach ($result as $field) echo $field['0'], ': ', $field['0'], '<br>';
```